# Making an outbound requests from Cloud Run

Tags: ssl, python-requests, tls1.2, firewall, google-cloud-run

I'm devolopping a python webserver running on Cloud Run. The server needs to be able to send some GET and POST requests to external APIs and that is failing. In this specific example, I'm trying to query the Google Maps api. But I have had the same error with other endpoints too.

Here is the error message:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='plus.codes', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api?address=78G9%2B2Q%2C%20Orem%2C%20UT%2C%20USA&key=xxxxxxxx (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)')))
```

I'm able to spin up the Docker container locally and have it to work well (requests are well going through) and this tells me the issue comes from my Cloud Run networking configuration.

I've tried to update the firewall rules with Ingress/Egress to allow all outgoing traffic but that did not help. But I've to admit I have only a little knowledge about networking.

The documentation also says that TLS traffic should not be used. But I'm not sure what that means but maybe that's related to the problem: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#tls

I've been on this issues for a few days, and I must say, I'm a bit puzzled that it is so difficult to perform a simple python requests from a Cloud Run instance. And there is not a lot of documentation, tutorials and stackoverflow threads about this seemingly basic task. As if I were the only one attempting to connect to the internet from a Cloud Run instance.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should look into **[Static Outbound IP Address](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip)**.

By default, a Cloud Run service uses a dynamic IP address pool to connect to external endpoints on the internet such as databases or API using IP address-based firewall. However, these requires connections from a static IP address. What you can do here is to configure Cloud Run to route requests using a static IP address.

You need to configure the Cloud Run service's VPC Egress to route all outbound traffic through a VPC Network that has a Cloud NAT gateway configured with the Static IP address.

You can follow the above documentation to enable a Cloud Run service to send requests using a static IP address.